# Алгоритм сортировки

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не могу понять в чём проблема.

Прохожу курс python, и по заданию надо написать свой алгоритм сортировки.
Я написал такой(*по моей логике **цикл проходит по каждому элементу списка и меняет его местами с минимальным элементом оставшегося среза списка***):

```
    a = [78, -32, 5, 39, 58, -5, -63, 57, 72, 9, 53, -1, 63, -97, -21, -94, -47, 57, -8, 60, -23, -72, -22, -79, 90, 96,
     -41, -71, -48, 84, 89, -96, 41, -16, 94, -60, -64, -39, 60, -14, -62, -19, -3, 32, 98, 14, 43, 3, -56, 71, -71,
     -67, 80, 27, 92, 92, -64, 0, -77, 2, -26, 41, 3, -31, 48, 39, 20, -30, 35, 32, -58, 2, 63, 64, 66, 62, 82, -62, 9,
     -52, 35, -61, 87, 78, 93, -42, 87, -72, -10, -36, 61, -16, 59, 59, 22, -24, -67, 76, -94, 59]

n = len(a)

for i in range(n):
     a[i], a[a.index(min(a[i:]))] = min(a[i:]), a[i]
print(a)
```

но он, по непонятной мне причине, возвращает исходный список.

Далее, по совету, я задал индекс минимального значения в отдельную переменную и код стал такой:

```
a = [78, -32, 5, 39, 58, -5, -63, 57, 72, 9, 53, -1, 63, -97, -21, -94, -47, 57, -8, 60, -23, -72, -22, -79, 90, 96,
     -41, -71, -48, 84, 89, -96, 41, -16, 94, -60, -64, -39, 60, -14, -62, -19, -3, 32, 98, 14, 43, 3, -56, 71, -71,
     -67, 80, 27, 92, 92, -64, 0, -77, 2, -26, 41, 3, -31, 48, 39, 20, -30, 35, 32, -58, 2, 63, 64, 66, 62, 82, -62, 9,
     -52, 35, -61, 87, 78, 93, -42, 87, -72, -10, -36, 61, -16, 59, 59, 22, -24, -67, 76, -94, 59]

n = len(a)

for i in range(n):
     b = a.index(min(a[i:]))
     a[i], a[b] = a[b], a[i]
print(a)
```

Но и тут не выдало желаемого результата. Пошёл смотреть в визуализаторе как проходит цикл.

И первые три итерации всё работает как надо, а на четвёртой(i = 3) почему то ***b = a.index(min(a[i:]))*** принимает значение вне указанного среза: ***b = 2***

Вот как это выглядит:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и дальше следовательно всё идёт наперекосяк.

Подскажите в чём причина? почему срез не работает или что то другое? Я не столько хочу решить задание и написать работающий алгоритм, сколько понять почему приведенные мной коды не работают.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что вы ищете индекс во всём списке, а не в его остатке. При наличии одинаковых чисел будут проблемы (в данном случае спотыкается на повторе значения -94). К счастью, у `.index()` есть параметр для начала поиска

```
 b = a.index(min(a[i:]), i)
```

решит задачу.

Вы осознаете, что такой алгоритм довольно медленный из-за двукратного прохода по списку? По сути это алгоритм сортировки выбором, для её осуществления достаточно на каждом проходе один раз пройтись по остатку массива, запоминая индекс минимума вручную.

Comment: Спасибо!
Я только начал знакомство с алгоритмами, поэтому пока что-то осознаю что-то не очень.
А по теме индекса, если можно задать начало поиска, то нужен ли тогда срез a[i:]? я думал он будет выполнять эту функцию, или что он тогда делает?

Comment: Да, срез нужен для поиска минимума только в этой части массива, у функции минимума нет возможности ограничить диапазон